# Automatically detect unnecessary ocaml open statements

Tags: ocaml

Say I have a bunch of ocaml modules with various `open` statements between them.  Some of these opens are unnecessary: they pull in a module but then never use any of the symbols.

Is there a programmatic way of finding these unnecessary imports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Warning 33. See the list [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/comp.html#sec266) or with `ocamlc -warn-help`.

To enable it, add `-w +33` to the compiler's command line. With ocamlbuild, add `true: warn(+33)` to your _tags.

Comment: I've spent the last few days mired in getting camlp5 syntax preprocessor machinery to compile, so the obvious check for a warning didn't occur to me! :)